# how to communicate from PC to Android device?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android apps, communicating with a device plugged in the USB port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803871/android-apps-communicating-with-a-device-plugged-in-the-usb-port)

We can access the android device from PC through USB port.
But here i want to do a bit different thing. That is,
I want to send message from PC to android device programmatically. That means there are two application one will be installed on android device and the other will be install on PC. I will send message from PC to the device and the device's app will get the message.

So how can I do this?
Can anyone know the answer or any advice, please answer me.

Thanks in Advance,
gsmaker

Comment: Do you want to send that message when connected trough USB or through the net?