# USB device for Android

Tags: java, android-emulator

I have a usb device that I have been using in windows OS. I am to connect that device to an Android Tablet. Can you suggest some API for developing my programs to communicate over the USB device using Android Operating system. 
Thank you so much for your interest

Comment: I believe Android doesn't support USB other than to communicate with a PC in development mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only do this on a rooted phone, and it is a complicated and "unsafe" process.

You can check this other post in stackoverflow forums where other references are mentioned. Some people have managed to do this but with rooted phone and some tricks, and also some projects are mentioned that were considering USB connection as a future goal, even though such development might not have been yet achieved. The link is: [Android apps, communicating with a device plugged in the USB port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803871/android-apps-communicating-with-a-device-plugged-in-the-usb-port)