# Receiving data from HTTP Post using Sockets

Tags: java, android, http, sockets

my requirement is to receive HTTP Post request using Socket in android(Contents are JSON file). When I print socket.getInputStream(), I get:

```
POST/HTTP/1.1
Content length:41
Content-type: application/json
Host:10.0.2.15:5001
Connection: Keep Alive
User-Agent: Apache HTTPClient/Unavailable(Java 1.4)

CRLF(Carriage return line feed)-  

Actual Contents of JSON<Data>
```

I used the link https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=7076709, but it prints only "Content-type: application/json
Host:10.0"(may be for length of 41) in Logcat.

My code is:

```
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    while(true){ 
    socket = serverSocket.accept();
    List<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>();
    String str;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
    headers.add(str);
    if (str.startsWith("Content-Length: "))
    {
    break; // and don't get the next line!
    }
    }
    int contentLength = Integer.parseInt(headers.get(headers.size() - 1).substring("Content-Length: ".length()));

   for(int j=0;j<headers.size();j++)
   {
    Log.d("Headers:",headers.get(j));
    }
    StringBuilder requestContent = new StringBuilder();
    int ch;
    for (int i = 0; i < contentLength; i++)
    {
    requestContent.append((char) reader.read());
    }
    Log.d("The request content is: ",""+requestContent);
```

This is my output: 
Headers:
 POST / HTTP/1.1
 Content-Length: 41

requestContent: 
 Content-Type: application/json
 Host: 10.

Can someone please guide me how it can be done? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ya i ve edited the question @Waqas

Comment: Why are you using sockets instead of an http library?

Comment: Please let me know if this scenario is possible(as my requirement is to implement so). Also I need some guidance about which HTTP library to use? Will it be light-weight? @artbristol

Comment: @user1741274 Have a look at the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329468/create-http-server-android

Comment: @artbristol . The asker is using sockets because he wants Android to be the http server. If it's possible to use http libraries for that, I'd like to know.

Comment: @Arvin there seem to be a few in the link I provided (I've never used one personally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DefaultHttpServerConnection conn = new DefaultHttpServerConnection();
conn.bind(serverSocket.accept(), new BasicHttpParams());
HttpRequest request = conn.receiveRequestHeader();
conn.receiveRequestEntity((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest)request);
HttpEntity entity = ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest)request).getEntity();
System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
```

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/tutorial/pdf/httpcore-tutorial.pdf for more reference