# jquery ajax and java server, lost data

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, localserver

i have this ajax function that looks like so

```
   $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "http://localhost:55556",
                      data: "lots and lots of pie",
                      cache: false,
                      success: function(result)
                      {     
                        alert("sent");


                      },
                      failure: function()
                      {
                              alert('An Error has occured, please try again.');
                      }
              });
```

and a server that looks like so

```
 clientSocket = AcceptConnection();

 inp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (clientSocket.getInputStream()));
 String requestString = inp.readLine();

 BufferedReader ed = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

   while(true){
          String tmp = inp.readLine();
          System.out.println(tmp);
     }
```

now the odd thing is when i send my ajax my server gets by using system.out

```
Host: localhost:55556
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 20
Origin: null
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

the question is where is the data that i sent through, where is lots of pie?

Comment: if it helps success: function(result)() in ajax, never gets achieved, so it never alerts "sent"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data should come after a blank line after the header lines, but I think the problem is that the data does not end with a newline character, and therefore, you cannot read it with the `.readLine()` method.

While looping through the header lines, you could look for the "Content-Length" line and get the length of the data. When you have reached the blank line, stop using `.readLine()`. Instead switch to reading one character at a time, reading the number of characters specified by the "Content-Length" header. I think you can find example code for this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21729100/859640).

If you can, I suggest you use a library to help with this. I think the [Apache HTTP Core library](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/) can help with this. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13086211/859640).

Comment: this seems like pretty solid advice, il give it a shot