# Communication between Two or more Android devices

Tags: android, client-server, wifi, communication, android-wifi

Here is my Scenario:

I have one Device that has app "a" installed on it.

I have one or more Devices that have app "b" installed.

I would like the devices with app "b" to be able to send a signal to app "a" to "register" the device. From app "a" i would like to be able to send messages back to some or all of the the devices. i was wondering if anyone knew any examples of this and the best way to go around doing it.

I have looked into Text Message and Bluetooth but I am looking for something along the lins of Direct connection, treating app "a" as a server.  I have looked briefly into sockets and was wondering peoples opinion of the best way to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try to do via wifi connectivity , like wifi-direct !!

Answer (score 0):

You can host a Http server (NanoHttp for example) on a and send standard http requests from b to a. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329468/create-http-server-android) post to learn more about the different Http servers.

Comment: Cheers, I will have a look at it tonight, better get back to work now though.