# How to run HTTP server on android?

Tags: android, httpserver

I have an Android `Activity` with `WebView` in it.
I have all my HTML, CSS and JavaScript files in `assets` folder.

I can run the `index.html` from `assets` in my `WebView` but it doesn't work correctly.
What I need is a VERY simple HTTP server running in that directory.

How can I do that?

Basically as simple as this:

> SimpleHTTPServer running on a mac.

```
$ cd /home/somedir
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

If it can't be assets directory, I can use any directory as long as I can set it.

any ideas?

thank you!

=================================

> EDIT

what I mean by "it doesn't work correctly" is that the `index.html` and other assets files make AJAX calls and to view the HTML correctly with the calls, there needs to be a local HTTP server running on that directory.

Comment: what does `"but it doesn't work correctly."` mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create http server android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329468/create-http-server-android)

Comment: I very highly doubt you want to create a webserver for this. Look into fixing the actual issue instead of working around the problem.

Comment: To program your self: NanoHttpd is a very fine webserver for Android.

Comment: @pskink please see the edit for what I mean when I say correctly.

Comment: @DaniëlvandenBerg I actually do want to create a local server. I am not trying to work around the issue.  Please see my edit, i tried to explain why I need this. thanks

Comment: actually `VebView` supports not only `http://` scheme but also `content://`, so all you need is a custom `ContentProvider` with overriden `openAssetFile` method, this way you can load whatever you like (even dynamic AJAX content)

Comment: @pskink I did not know that but before I tried that, I was able to make it work.  Please see my answer before.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

You dont need to be running a web server on your android app.

A more detailed example of this can be found here: 
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted#loading_html_files_from_the_file_system

Comment: I'm already doing that but that will not load angularJS or ajax.  All my content of the html page isn't there, that is why I said "it doesn't work correctly" before.

Comment: Have you tried to call `setJavaScriptEnabled` on the Web View? I have updated the answer

Comment: I tried that.. still doesn't work. It doesn't even work on a computer chrome browser if there is no local server there.  I had to do `$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer`  on mac terminal to make it work on the computer.

Comment: this does not handle dynamic content like AJAX

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Marty's answer, I was able to take it a step further and make it work.

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

`setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs` made it all work!

hope this helps someone. thanks!

Comment: i dont see how you can handle AJAX calls here

Comment: @pskink I believe what you're saying but my content is viewing properly as of right now. I'm still working on finishing it. If i run into a problem, i will try the custom `ContentProvider` option