# Can I use ajax to send and retrieve data between 2 android devices?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I was just wondering, also asking here because I couldn't find an answer (in English) that explained this to me, Is it posible to request data say from IP adress 10.22.44.27 to 10.48.38.28 so basically acting as a global connection between these two devices instead of requestig info from a server? Is that possible, do I need third party tools / Libraries / node.js and will it work on android?

Comment: Technically you can but android devices need to understand incoming requests and respond properly, like webservers. I'm not sure if you can achieve this with pure android because I'm not that familiar with android ecosystem. You will probably need a third party lib/app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use ajax to send and retrieve data between 2 android devices?

Ajax is the act of making an HTTP request from JavaScript (embedded in a web page) without leaving the page. You need a client to make the request and an HTTP server to receive it and make the response.

You can run a web browser on Android (several are available).

You can run [an HTTP server on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329468/how-to-create-a-http-server-in-android).

So, yes, it is possible.

> instead of requestig info from a server

No, by definition, Ajax needs a server.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way that I can achieve a data transfer from anywhere in the world to anywhere using JavaScript (and any libraries)?