# Communicate among 2 apps over 2 devices for app data

Tags: android, service, android-contentprovider

So, i have this app created which takes care of my daily cash spends. I am keeping this data in a sqlite database. Now, i want to create an app that sort of work likes a client app to this where a user can request data for a specific date and interact with it. The data is only on my device and not on any web server.
this 2nd app will be installed on a seperate device.
I have already looked into content providers and android services but i am unable to understand the correct approach to this problem, since the data is not kept on any web server but on a single device within an app. 
What i believe is  can make this data accessible via a content provider, but how do i make this second app communicate with the content provider from a seperate device?

Comment: _but how do i make this second app communicate with the content provider from a separate device?_ Ans: You can't. You need both app in same device for this. I suggest you to use a webserver

Comment: can i use this app as a server for the 2nd app?

Comment: no, you have to use a webserver

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329468/how-to-create-a-http-server-in-android