# embedding golang server with flutter

Tags: flutter, kotlin, go, gomobile, gqlgen

I have web server written in golang which uses graphql package [gqlgen](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen) and [gorm](https://gorm.io/index.html) for database.

Since golang can be compiled and run on android I wanted to create offline version of my app where sqlite can be used for offline storage and import my whole server as an **aar**.

I have successfully built **aar** and add it on my flutter using gomobile by following instructions [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Mobile)

When I run my app, server is started on android it seems to work just fine and when opening `http://localhost:8080/` on emulator's chrome app I am seeing graphql playground runs without any problem just like I see on browser in windows.

The only problem I face is that flutter app just shows a blank screen while server runs in background. The following are the logs printed when app is started

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62561/DyGpOhyuekw=/ws
Syncing files to device sdk gphone64 x86 64...
I/GoLog   ( 6295): connect to http://localhost:8080/ for GraphQL playground
W/ux.offline( 6295): type=1400 audit(0.0:38): avc: denied { read } for name="somaxconn" dev="proc" ino=74990 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c149,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_net:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=com.nux.offline
```

I think maybe problem lies on the above logs `avc: denied { read } for name="somaxconn"` or something is causing the blocking of ui thread since its like flutter don't render a thing.

I am using flutter plugin to start server and this is ServerPlugin.kt

```kotlin
package com.mahesabu.server.server

import androidx.annotation.NonNull

import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.FlutterPlugin
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result
import lib.Lib.startServer

/** ServerPlugin */
class ServerPlugin : FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler {
    /// The MethodChannel that will the communication between Flutter and native Android
    ///
    /// This local reference serves to register the plugin with the Flutter Engine and unregister it
    /// when the Flutter Engine is detached from the Activity
    private lateinit var channel: MethodChannel

    override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
        channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger, "server")
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(this)
    }

    override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
        if (call.method == "startServer") {
            try {
                val port = startServer() //from golang bindings
                result.success(port)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                result.error("Error in starting server", "${e.message}", null);
            }
        } else {
            result.notImplemented()
        }
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(null)
    }
}
```

And this is is dart code

```dart
class Server {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('server');

  static Future<String?> startServer() async {
    try {
      final String? port = await _channel.invokeMethod('startServer');
      return port;
    } catch (e) {
      log('startServer error: ${e.toString()}');
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

and my app's main is as follows

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:server/server.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final port = await Server.startServer(); //problem

  print('port $port'); //This don't print

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

On go side this how i start server

```golang
//start.go
package util

import (
    "github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/handler"
    "github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/playground"
    "log"
    "my-project/graph"
    "my-project/graph/generated"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

const defaultPort = "8080"

// StartServer This way so that it can be invoked via libs
func StartServer(Offline bool) string {
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = defaultPort
    }

    db := InitDB(Offline)

    config := generated.Config{Resolvers: &graph.Resolver{
        DB:     db,
    }}

    srv := handler.NewDefaultServer(generated.NewExecutableSchema(config))

    http.Handle("/", playground.Handler("GraphQL playground", "/query"))
    http.Handle("/query", srv)

    log.Printf("connect to http://localhost:%s/ for GraphQL playground", port)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil))

    return port
}
```

and this is lib for generating bindings with gomobile

```
//lib.go
package lib

import "my-project/util"

// StartServer This way so that it can be invoked via libs
func StartServer() string {
    return util.StartServer(true)
}
```

Any help on fixing this will be appreciated.

**Edit**

I think problem occurs when embedded server tries to create a new port. I don't know if it is possible for an app to open a new port in android just like nodejs, golang open things like http://localhost:8080.

Now I think if there is a way to create port then I can run my app successfully but I don't know how exactly.

I was thinking if I can find any available port on android and use to start server maybe this stack could be possible. In kotlin something like this may work in finding port.

```kotlin
import java.net.ServerSocket

fun main() {
   val serverPort = ServerSocket(0)
   print(serverPort.toString())
}
```

but it crashes on android app when I try similar thing.

I have uploaded a repository on GitHub showing what I intend to do. It's just a simple golang server using gin and android app (with no flutter) [it is available here](https://github.com/kateile/android-app-with-golang).

Comment: "I don't know if it is possible for an app to open a new port in android just like nodejs, golang open things like http://localhost:8080" - What about firstly try to run an HTTP server in android like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329468/how-to-create-a-http-server-in-android . If that succeeds, try to find the differences in dealing with ports.

Comment: And please be sure you have correct permission in androidmanifest.xml

Comment: @ch271828n thanks for your response. It pointed me in the right direction, now I just realized I was trying to start server on the main thread and that was the root of all problems. Now I have realized this stack is possible and should just find a correct way of handling starting server on different thread. So I am now searching how to do it correctly

Comment: @ch271828n and for confirmation it is sure possible to run HTTP server on android.

Comment: Great! Looking forward to your solving the problem!

Comment: I had a similar problem, so I implemented Flutter realtimedatabase with async.

Answer (score 2):

> "I don't know if it is possible for an app to open a new port in android just like nodejs, golang open things like localhost:8080"

To find out the root cause, try to run an HTTP server in android, such as [How to create a HTTP server in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329468). If that succeeds, try to find the differences about how they deal with ports.

In addition, please be sure you have correct permission in androidmanifest.xml.

(Rephrased from my comments)