# PC to mobile USB communication

Tags: usb

I am using **Windows 7 as OS** on my PC. I am looking to create an application wherein I shall send AT commands to Mobile, programatically.
As of now I am looking towards achieving this with USB data cable connection between PC and Mobile. My initial approach was to use JAVA. Though I soon realized that most API development for communication between JAVA and USB port is dead for windows, and none of these APIs support Windows 7.
Can someone please suggest which language would be best for doing this?

Thanks,
Ishan Aggarwal

Comment: you didn't reveal what type of device.

Comment: The device I am looking to connect to PC is Cell phones. I want no limitation on brand, though I want to start with Blackberry.

Comment: Maybe it a little bit late but currently I work with  http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/MobileDevice_Library  
That one should support windows side (its written in C but you can create a C++ project in VS) and I know it possible to integrate it to C#. Let me know if it may help and I Will post more accurate answer.

Comment: See my answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/25015990/216057

Answer (score 2):

For **Android** to create connection with PC, you need forward the same port by using `adb` command (Android SDK), like:

```
adb forward tcp:7612 tcp:7612
```

In **Java** it seems like:

```
private int port = 7612;
....

/**
 * Runs the android debug bridge command of forwarding the ports
 *
 */
private void execAdb() {
    // run the adb bridge
    try {
        String runP = "adb forward tcp:" + port + " tcp:" + port + "";

        System.out.println("Run command through cmd: " + runP);



        Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(runP);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(p.getErrorStream());
        if (sc.hasNext()) {
            while (sc.hasNext()) System.out.println(sc.next());
            System.out.println("Cannot start the Android debug bridge");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After that you can implement any TCP client/server code since the port is defined and you can use default IP like: 127.0.0.1

For **iOS** use Objective C lang.

Comment: Hi Maxim, Thanks for the help, though I have few questions in mind: 1. You have used port number 7612, is there a specific reason for this? Is this port defined as USB port?

Comment: I used this port as free one (always). Never got problems with