# is serial communication is possible in android via USB

Tags: android, usb

I am using USB and connect it to the android device and Pc..can I send message from Pc to device and Device to pc?
                       Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Please be more clear and specific. give more details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android apps, communicating with a device plugged in the USB port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803871/android-apps-communicating-with-a-device-plugged-in-the-usb-port)

Comment: This question is a duplicate of numerous posts on SO, I picked the one that seemed well fleshed out. Please use the search before asking a new question - many things have already been asked and answered on SO.

Comment: how can it be possible but..Actually I want to connectivity it with terminal on PC

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to communicate between an android device and a PC is either to use an Internet service, or to connect the android device to the same wifi access point as the PC and use normal TCP networking methods.

If USB debugging is enabled on the android device and it is connected to a pc with the ADB tool from the sdk, then you can set up an ADB port forward.  This will allow the PC to make a TCP connection to the android device, and then bidirectional traffic can flow.  However, the port forward does not itself allow the android device to initiate a connection to the PC, though you can accomplish this by setting up tunneling (potential with ssh or some other solution).

Some implementations of tethering (use the android device to provide Internet to the PC) have the side effect of establishing a general network connection between the android device and the PC, at which point either side could potentially initiate a connection.  However, it would take some customization to keep the PC from trying to do its networking through the android device, potentially using up your mobile service plan unnecessarily.