# Android USB application

Tags: java, android, usb, communication

I have a have been doing my research on a program in which an android application makes a communication with a Desktop computer through a USB connection. I did find out that Android 3.1 allows USB communication, but I have no idea how to proceed on it. I'd be very helpful if someone could tell me how this is done.

Thanks
Nik

Answer (score 0):

You can use this API.

[Accessory Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html)

More detailed information can be had from this link as well.

[Android apps, communicating with a device plugged in the USB port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803871/android-apps-communicating-with-a-device-plugged-in-the-usb-port)

I am not sure you can test this using an emulator.So develop an application and deploy it in a `real device` and `connect` that device to your PC `via USB port` for testing.