# Why does USB mouse works in Android Tablet with USB host disabled?

Tags: android, usb

I have developed an android app that is connecting to a usb card reader. I have tested the app, running without any problem in Samsung Tab 10.1(old version).

Then I purchased a 7 inches MSI tablet E71 and deployed the same app and connects to the same usb card reader but the MSI tablet cannot detects the usb card reader.
I google around and have some ideas on this problem ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183792/android-usb-host-and-hidden-devices) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110555/how-to-detect-usb-device-in-android-tablet-which-acts-as-usb-host))

I have checked the MSI tablet using adb, the "**android.hardware.usb.host.xml**" cannot be found in it. Then I check in the Samsung Tab 10.1, and I can see the "android.hardware.usb.host.xml" file is there. So I can conclude that, the MSI tablet USB host mode is disabled (correct me if I'm wrong or missing some other check). But I connected USB mouse into the MSI tablet and it works.

So my questions are:

- how can the USB mouse works in the MSI tablet since USB host mode is disabled?
- can I say that if I have put the "android.hardware.usb.host.xml" into the MSI tablet(by rooting), it will be able to detect my usb card reader?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can give it a try, but in my experience , I didn't find any file who is responsible for mouse to be working. if it is that the XML file you are telling is a USB host who is also for mouse, then I don't think so that card reader will have any problem to be read by MSI tab