# Writing SMS data to serial port

Tags: android, vb.net, jakarta-ee

I have built an SMS Service which runs when the mobile phone is on. This service updates a database when a SMS is received and then creates an entry in a log file. Finally, the SMS is deleted. I want my system to be able to sync the database between the Android mobile phone and a PC. For this to happen, I want to send/receive data on a serial port to which the Android device is connected. Is it possible to do so in Android? What would be the best way to implement the sync mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to use the modem Incorporated in the Phone?Or you just want to get all the sms from the Android SMS Aplication?

Comment: Actually I wish to send data to mobile phones when some one necessary and receive data whenever mobile phone received sms or data.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem seems to be the communication with the android app. over the USB connection. This has been asked before on SO:

[Android apps, communicating with a device plugged in the USB port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803871/android-apps-communicating-with-a-device-plugged-in-the-usb-port)

This [link](http://www.anothem.net/archives/2010/10/15/android-usb-connection-to-pc/) may also be useful.

You can easily establish a channel on a USB port for your Android application and desktop application to communicate, developing your own sync mechanism. However, this may limit you to USB connection if you choose certain approaches. The Socket-based approach has the advantage that it can be easily ported to a remote wireless connection, enabling your sync mechanism to work on WiFi too.